# Remove Element From List Without Index

Tags: python

So I'm iterating over items in a list in this way:

```
for virus in viruses:
    do stuff
    remove virus
```

If I had the index, I could just do del virus[i], and I could obviously tweak the code to do something like `for index in range(0, len(viruses))`, but that starts to make the code ugly pretty quickly for the other things I want to do within the for loop. Is there anyway I can just remove based on the name of the virus I am currently iterating over?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about this:

```
for virus in viruses[:]:
    # do stuff
    viruses.remove(virus)  # remove "virus" from the original list
```

`viruses[:]` creates a copy of our `viruses` list. As a note, you can also use `list(oldlist)` to copy lists (I find this a little more readable, but either will work). You can read more about lists in python [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Answer (score 5):

To remove an item by its value just use [`list.remove()`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

Removing elements from a list while you are iterating over it can cause some unexpected problems, so make sure you are iterating over a copy:

```
for virus in viruses[:]:
    # do stuff
    viruses.remove(virus)
```

Answer (score 1):

lists have a method `remove()`, using which you can remove an element by value,

and if you're modifying a list as well as iterating over it then you should use `reversed()`, otherwise the iteration will miss some elements:

```
for virus in reversed(viruses):
    viruses.remove(virus)
```

a simple example:

```
In [203]: lis=range(0,10)

In [206]: for x in reversed(lis):
   .....:     if x%2==0:                #remove even numbers
   .....:         lis.remove(x)
   .....:         
   .....:         

In [207]: lis
Out[207]: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

or use a shallow copy:

```
In [212]: lis=range(10)

In [213]: for x in lis[:]:
    if x%2==0:
        lis.remove(x)
   .....:         
   .....:         

In [216]: lis
Out[216]: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Although one of your options is to use `remove()`, that may return an error. Another option is to treat viruses (which is assumed to be a list) as a stack (or a queue)

```
for _ in xrange(len(viruses)):
    virus = viruses.pop()
    # do stuff with virus
```

If `viruses` is instead a dictionary (and `virus` the key), then the key is all you need to delete it:

```
import copy
for virus in copy.copy(viruses):
    # do stuff with virus
    del viruses[virus]
```

See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html for more information

Comment: You can't change a dictionary while you're iterating it.
`RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
`